# How to install Google colab on local runtime?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[This example](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/drive.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA) shows how to access GDrive on colab:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

This only works for hosted runtime:

[image: Available runtimes]

For local runtime it shows:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'
```

How to make this work for local runtime as well?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Drive desktop client seems to be the only choice so far

Comment: Damn. I was hoping to be able to run the same code locally and remotely without modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Drive desktop client](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) directly.